# Can bookmarks be imported on IOS ver?

Tags: ios

I know you can import bookmarks on the PC version, but is there a way to do it on IOS's new App 'Red Browser'? I'm guessing it's probably not a good idea to have bookmarks from other unsecured browsers imported into Tor. Yes/No? 
I'm also assuming that Tor 'Red Browser' for IOS is less secure in every way compared to Tor on a PC correct?

Comment: Currently it is unclear to me what your question is about. As far as I see it [Red Browser](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/red-browser-private-web-browser/id507149204?mt=8) is some browsing app with no connection to Tor. [Onion Browser](https://mike.tig.as/onionbrowser/) is a web browser with Tor support for iOS. This might help more.
Please clarify your question. I'll close it for now, but it can be reopened after your edits.